# How should I decode bytes (using ASCII) without losing any "junk" bytes if xmlcharrefreplace and backslashreplace don't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, byte

I have a network resource which returns me data that should (according to the specs) be an ASCII encoded string. But in some rare occasions, I get junk data.

One resource for example returns `b'\xd3PS-90AC'` whereas another resource, for the same key returns `b'PS-90AC'`

The first value contains a non-ASCII string. Clearly a violation of the spec, but that's unfortunately out of my control. None of us are 100% certain that this really *is* junk or data which should be kept.

The application calling on the remote resources saves the data in a local database for daily use. I could simply do a `data.decode('ascii', 'replace')` or `..., 'ignore')` but then I would lose data which could turn out to be useful later on.

My immediate reflex was to use `'xmlcharrefreplace'` or `'backslashreplace'` as error handler. Simply because it would result in a displayable string. But then I get the following error: `TypeError: don't know how to handle UnicodeDecodeError in error callback`

The only error-handler which worked was `surrogateescape`, but this seems to be intended for filenames. On the other hand, for *my* intent and purpose it would work.

Why are `'xmlcharrefreplace'` and `'backslashreplace'` not working? I don't understand the error.

For *example*, an expected execution would be:

```
>>> data = b'\xd3PS-90AC'
>>> new_data = data.decode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
>>> print(repr(new_data))
'&#d3;PS-90AC'
```

This is a *contrived* example. My aim is to *not lose* any data. If I would use the `ignore` or `replace` error-handler, the byte in question would essentially disappear, and information is lost.

Comment: I don't clearly understand what is the expected "output". You want the "ASCII" string _and_ the "junk" bytes together (say `u'\u00d3PS-90AC'`) ? Or something like the result of `data.decode('unicode_escape')` ?

Comment: I added some example execution. Not that the example output comes a bit from the top of my head. If it uses a different syntax, that's okay.

Comment: I add the tag Python3 as this is implied by your example. Or am I wrong?

Comment: It's okayish ;) as `surrogateescape` and `backslashreplace` only exist in Python3. At the moment the library I am writing is still in use by *one* Python 2 application, so a Python2 solution would be preferred, but we are planning to port that one remaining app to Python3 eventually. So it's okay... Worst case, we have to port it *now* :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> data = b'\xd3PS-90AC'
>>> data.decode('ascii', 'surrogateescape')
'\udcd3PS-90AC'
```

It does not use *html entities* but it is a decent starting point. If not sufficient, you will have to register your own error handler using [codecs.register_error](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.register_error) I assume.

For Python3:

```
def handler(err):
    start = err.start
    end = err.end
    return ("".join(["&#{0};".format(err.object[i]) for i in range(start,end)]),end)

import codecs
codecs.register_error('xmlcharreffallback', handler)
data = b'\xd3PS-90AC'
data.decode('ascii', 'xmlcharreffallback')
```

For Python 2

```
def handler(err):
    start = err.start
    end = err.end
    return (u"".join([u"&#{0};".format(ord(err.object[i])) for i in range(start,end)]),end)

import codecs
codecs.register_error('xmlcharreffallback', handler)
data = b'\xd3PS-90AC'
data.decode('ascii', 'xmlcharreffallback')
```

Both producing:

```
'&#211;PS-90AC'
```

Comment: I have been reading up on the topic. And I'm not sure anymore if my original idea to use `xmlcharrefreplace` is such a good idea. The referenced value points to a "Unicode code point". And by looking up `211`, I found `ȑ` (utf-8 byte value `c8 91`). So I'm not sure how you would get back from `211` to `\xd3`. And I think using `surrogateescape` might be less ambiguous... :\

Comment: Maybe we are focusing too much on "how" without really knowing "what" you are trying to do. Wouldn't it time for an other question :) ?

Comment: @exhuma BTW `211`(10) is `d3`(16). This would be not much more than a simple dec->hex conversion. That being said, I would personally push toward using Unicode code point. But once angin without clarification on your usage of that "junkie string", it is hard to tell.

Comment: you're right. I think I've been looking too much at bytes the last two days. I probably should take a break.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, wanted to add that as of python 3.5, `backslashreplace` works for decoding, so you no longer have to add a custom error handler.